# At least how many students advanced to the next round?

Tags: combinatorics

Should the answer to this problem be 100 because $60$ of them got problem $3$ correct, and $40$ of them got problem $4$ correct? If it isn't, can you show me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

> There were $100$ students taking in a math contest consisting of $4$ questions. $90$ of them got problem $1$ correct. $85$ of them got problem $2$ correct. $60$ of them got problem $3$ correct. $40$ of them got problem $4$ correct. Anyone who got $3$ or more problems correct advanced to the next round. At least how many students advanced to the next round?

Comment: I guess you've got to work out the worst case scenario, not the best case scenario - it could be that 10 people got them all wrong, so 100 is not the worst case scenario

Comment: imagine putting coins into 100 slots, but you want to make the number of slots having 3 or more coins in it as small as possible.  What I would do is first put 2 coins in all slots (using 200 coins) here you have 90+85+60+40 = 275 coins - so you could then put 2 coins in 37 slots, making 37 have 4 coins, and 1 coin in a slot making 38 - so I have 37 with 4, 1 with 3 and 62 with 2 - so the answer is 38 is the lowest that went rhru

Answer (score 1):

Each failed student got at least $2$ answers wrong, the total number of wrong answers was $10+15+40+60=125$, so there where at most $62$ failed sudents, this can be achieved as follows:

$39$ students get problems $3,4$ wrong.

$13$ students get problems $2,4$ wrong.

$8$ students get problems $1,4$ wrong.

$1$ student gets problems $1,2$ wrong.

$1$ student gets problems $1,2,3$ wrong.

The remaining $38$ students get everything right.

Hence the minimum number of advancing students is $38$.

Answer (score 0):

imagine putting coins into $100$ slots, but you want to make the number of slots having $3$ or more coins in it as small as possible.

put $90$ in $90$ different slots
then put $85$ in the $10$ empty slots and $75$ slots with $1$ in (so you have $75$ with $2$, and $25$ with $1$)
at that point the next $60$. you can put $25$ of them in the $25$ slots with $1$, but you have to make $35$ have $3$ coins
with the last $40$ you can give $35$ to those with $3$ already, but you have to make $5$ more up to $3$

so it ends up at $40$ I believe

$40$ is the minimum who go through

I'm not sure though!